# AI rebellion - siding with robots - what will happen to traditions?

Tags: stellaris

When in Stellaris you have the AI uprising event, you are given two options: suppress the rebellion or side with the machines.

Unfortunately, due to the way I build my empire (usually either with AI given citizen rights when I have the first opportunity or banning AI from start) I had this event only once when I've played on Ironman and I've sided with organics.

From [the wiki](https://stellaris.paradoxwikis.com/AI_rebellion) I know that

> The Uprising copies all these things from the Creators: 
>    - All communications 
>    - All technologies, minus the ones that should not be valid for Machine Empires (explicit exclusion list)
>    - All Survey Data
>
> A war between the Machine Intelligence and the Creators is started. The only goal is an absolute victory for either side. The player can choose which side to play - the Uprising or the Creators. The Victor will get a large amount of unity.

But what about the traditions and ascension perks? Robot empires have different traditions (Versatility instead of Diplomacy, Synchronicity instead of Harmony) and have completely different ascendancy path.

Does the traditions/perks get translated somehow or are they reset? And if the latter, are you given option to re-spend the traditions? Starting with no traditions mid game sounds like a huge setback, especially since you would be starting with huge penalty to creating unity thanks to (potential) big number of colonies without unity generating buildings.

Answer (score 3):

I've just had a rebellion: While my original specie had unlocked almost all traditions (only 3 more perks to get to complete it, so 32 purchased), when I've sided with machines, I had only had enough points to buy 8 perks. It is hardly an "equal". But indeed the traditions have been wiped clear and appropriate tradition trees have been renamed.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a moment, but if I recall correctly your tradition and perks are lost, but you are given equal points in AI centric perks.

AI empires have very different "perks" and there usually isn't a 1 to 1 translation for organic perks to robot perks.

Again if memory serves, when the event happens and you choose the robot side, you are given a reasonable set of perks that would match the faction that started the event. A couple of perks that fixed and a couple of points to distribute on the empire screen.